# TypeError: readonly assignment error with React application in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I have the following minimally-functional React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

var downloadBlobAsFile = (function closure() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function downloadBlobAsFile(blob, fileName) {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = objectURL;
    a.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);  
    }, 100);
  };
})();

class MyWidget extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someData: "abcd1234..."
    };
    this.handleDownloadClick = this.handleDownloadClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleDownloadClick() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toISOString();
    var fn = "result-" + n + ".txt";
    if (this.state.someData) {
      downloadBlobAsFile(new Blob([this.refs.dataContainer.innerHTML], {type: "plain/text"}), fn);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button value="download" onClick={this.handleDownloadClick}>Download</Button>;
        <div className="hidden-container" ref="dataContainer">{this.state.someData}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyWidget;
```

Webpack can build a bundle containing this component.

However, in Safari 10.1, the developer console reports the following fatal error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property
```

The application does not render in Safari.

This is related to the following chunk of code:

```
var downloadBlobAsFile = (function closure() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function downloadBlobAsFile(blob, fileName) {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = objectURL;
    a.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);  
    }, 100);
  };
})();
```

If I comment out this code block, Safari will load and render the application (albeit with no functionality from this function).

I do not need to comment out this block for Chrome or Firefox clients, only Safari.

What is the reason for this error, and what steps can I take to modify my component to allow use of this function with Safari clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code to change in the `downloadBlobAsFile()` function is:

```
a.style = "display: none";
```

To:

```
a.style.display = "none";
```

This resolves the read-only error in Safari and preserves functionality in other clients.

Comment: Thank you very much for following up on your own question. This solved my problem exactly too. `domNode.style['font-weight'] = 'bold'` compared to `domNode.style = "font-weight: bold"`.